# bash - at refusing to execute script?

Tags: java, bash, job-scheduling, at-job

Let's say I have a script to start some java stuff

start.sh

```
myStuff=10.0.0.13
port=11212
servers=(10.0.0.9 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.11 10.0.0.12 10.0.0.14)
T=$1
R=$2

nohup java -jar myJar.jar -l ${myStuff} -p ${port} -t $T -r $R -m "${servers[@]/%/:11212}" &
```

If I start the script manually

```
./start.sh 64 1
```

for example, everything works as it should

now

```
echo "nohup ./start.sh 64 1" | at now
```

however, does nothing.

Why?

I've started similar scripts like this before (none that called java, though) and I can't seem to figure out how they differ.

**EDIT**

well, not quite nothing, the job DOES get scheduled and does disappear from the `atq`, but the jar is not started and there is no `nohup.out` anywhere.

*EDIT 2*

note that

```
echo "nohup ./start.sh 64 1 > help &" | at now
```

does create a `help` file (not a `nohup.out` file, though) but it's empty.

*EDIT 3*

note that changing the start.sh such that the path to the java binary is hardcoded:

```
nohup /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar myJar.jar -l ${myStuff} -p ${port} -t $T -r $R  -m "${servers[@]/%/:11212}" &
```

doesn't help either.

*EDIT 4*

```
echo "nohup java -version > help &" | at now
```

creates an empty `help` file (but no `nohup.out`).

Whereas

```
echo "nohup java -version > help 2>&1 &" | at now
```

will print

```
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

into the `help` file (and not create a `nohup.out` file either).

*EDIT 5*

getting rid of the nohup, i.e.

```
java -jar myJar.jar ...
```

and then

```
echo "./start.sh 64 1" | at now
```

doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think your environment setting (like JAVA_HOME etc.) will be different depending whether you run the command at the command line or from `at`. look at the `nohup.out` file, or redirect the output of your command in a file.

Comment: @ThomasStets there is no ``nohup.out``

Comment: @ThomasStets nor does redirecting the output give any further information (see edits)

Comment: I don't see a problem in `echo "nohup ./start.sh 64 1" | at now` part. Can you enable logs from Java? Perhaps log4j into a file?

Comment: @alok My application would already create log files ... IF it were started.

Comment: @ThomasStets hardcoding the java location doesn't change a thing (see edits).

Comment: Could you please try running something like `java -version` and see what goes into the `help` file from your *Edit 2*? Also maybe redirect stderr into it by appending `2>&1`?

Comment: @alok done. see edit above

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but there is no need to run the job in the background if you are using `at`. Backgrounding and using `nohup` allows you to continue with your current shell and log out without interrupting the job when you run it manually. If the `at` daemon is running it for you, it is already being managed by a long-lived process. Try just running `java ...` in the foreground in the script.

Comment: You need to specify the absolute path to `start.sh`.

Comment: @chepner doesn't change anything (see edit)

Comment: @gsl no, I do not. If it wouldn't find the script, it wouldn't be able to produce the ``help`` file, would it? (Also, I tried.)